# Get Color from this type of number -16776961

Tags: c#, winforms

i have below code and its color convert into something like this number , my question is how to get color from this type of number

> "-16776961" i want convert this number into color

```
 if (DialogResult.OK == colorDialog1.ShowDialog())
            {

                txt.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
                txt.Tag = colorDialog1.Color.ToArgb();
            }

 objBO.Current.BackGroundColor =  txtBackColor.Tag.ToString();
```

Comment: any reason doing the reverse of `ToArgb()` doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your color with the method `ToArgb()`, you might just use the method `FromArgb()` to get the `int` back to a `System.Drawing.Color`. Yes, its that freaking easy!

```
System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(-16776961) -> "{Name=ff0000ff, ARGB=(255, 0, 0, 255)}"
```